# Atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ fell at a Pleistocene interglacial-glacial transition. Ocean absorption vs biosphere absorption

Tags: oceanography, carbon-cycle, biogeochemistry, glaciation, biomass

CO<sub>2</sub> levels fell during the last interglacial-glacial transition until the [Last Glacial Maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Glacial_Maximum) in the [Pleistocene](https://www.britannica.com/science/Pleistocene-Epoch).

[image]

I can think of two causes for the reduction of CO<sub>2</sub>:

- **Ocean absorption**. The temperature dropped and the ocean began to absorb more CO<sub>2</sub>, according to [Henry's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law).
- **Biosphere absorption**. For example, fixed nitrogen is a limiting nutrient for algae in the low-latitude ocean, and its oceanic inventory may have been higher during the ice ages, thus helping to lower atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> during those intervals (Ren et al.,2009).

What was the relative role (quantitatively) that both process played in the CO<sub>2</sub> fall?

Was the ocean the main CO<sub>2</sub> sink and the biosphere absorption secondary? Or conversely both played a similar role (or even biosphere was a larger sink)?

Are there other sinks than biosphere and oceans?

---

**H. Ren, D. M. Sigman1, A. N. Meckler, B. Plessen, R. S. Robinson, Y. Rosenthal, G. H. Haug (2009)**: "Foraminiferal isotope evidence of reduced nitrogen fixation in the ice age Atlantic Ocean" *Science* 09 Jan 2009: Vol. 323, Issue 5911, pp. 244-248
DOI: 10.1126/science.1165787

Comment: Your graphs only go back 1.3 million years. The Pleistocene started 2.6 million years ago or so. What is the point of including those noninclusive graphs? What is the point of this question?

Comment: CO2 levels don't fall drastically at the beginning of the Pleistocene. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-12357-5. They fall during the Pliocene and mainly fluctuate between 180 and 320 during the Pleistocene following the Milankovic cycles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124167/discussion-between-universal-learner-and-earthworm).

Comment: @David Hammen Is it more clear now? I know probably there is not any quantitative study from any o both sizes (how much is stored in the ocean or how much biomass the biosfere earn during a transition). If you have a qualitative answer or opinion I would like to read it as an answer or a comment. I know this is a question for a paleoclimatologist expert in carbone cycle, but you are the closest to that I have seen in the forum. Maybe an oceanographer could give also a qualitative answer

Comment: I suspect you are confusing cause and effect, and I know that your two causes are far from complete. You have forgotten about mountains for one thing, and for another you have forgotten ocean currents. Did the formation of the Isthmus of Panama play a role? Maybe. This is highly debated. Did the Rocky Mountains, the Alps, and the Himalaya play a role? Maybe. But this too is highly debated.  Is the division between the Pliocene and the Pleistocene rather arbitrary? There is a marker for that division, but whether it is geologically / biologically significant once again is highly debated.

Comment: @David Hammen My question isn't from the Pliocene-Pleistocene boundary. The paper describes Last Glacial Maximum relative to the current interglacial (Holocene). Anyhow I get as an answer *it is highly debated*, thank you very much. The question might also be interested to be asked about the Pliocene-Pleistocene Boundary, as Pleistocene is considered itself a Glacial Age and there is a CO2 decay at the boundary (bigger). I edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Universal_learner: I performad a casual search for the cause of the CO2 decline during oxygen isotope stages 4 and 3 (the red frame) and found work that supports your assumption that the ocean uptake played a major role. Unfortuantely I don't have time and deep enough knowledge for a good answer.

Comment: @Earthworm can you link me the work to read it?

Comment: It doesn't show-up again, bloody search engine bubble. It was about the North Atlantic, and it contained something about iron fertiliziation of the ocean from the African continent in relation to co2 solubility. It was a local work, and limited to these factors. Hth ...

Answer (score 1):

CO2 follows temp, not the other way around. When temperatures decline, biological activity decreases and available biologically derived carbon also declines.  When temps increase and soil carbon outputs improve freely available carbon dioxide reintroduces into the biosphere. Biological absorption is more paramount, because as frozen tundra, non-fossilized plants such as peat and bogs proliferate in cooler climates.